# Simple Select Case VBA Code not Running

Tags: vba, excel

When I assign this macro to a button and run it nothing happens no error, nothing. I don't get why nothing is happening. It is supposed to look at cell C4 and use the score there to assign a letter grade and a "pass" or "fail" to cells D4 and E4 based on the score.

```
Sub Grade()
  Dim x As Range
  Dim y As Range
  Dim z As Range
  Dim w As Integer

  Set x = Worksheets("Grades").Range("C4")
  Set y = Worksheets("Grades").Range("D4")
  Set z = Worksheets("Grades").Range("E4")
  w = x.Value

  Select Case w
    Case 0 - 50
        y.Value = "F"
        z.Value = "Fail"
    Case 51 - 59
        y.Value = "D"
        z.Value = "Fail"
    Case 60 - 65
        y.Value = "D"
        z.Value = "Pass"
    Case 66 - 75
        y.Value = "C"
        z.Value = "Pass"
    Case 76 - 90
        y.Value = "B"
        z.Value = "Pass"
    Case 91 - 100
        y.Value = "A"
        z.Value = "Pass"
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: All your number ranges need to be like this `Case 0 to  50`

Comment: Step 1: Put in `call msgbox ("Hi")` at the very start to confirm the code is actually called.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly now!

Comment: You can do this with formulas..BTW, I'd have thought you of all people would have a descriptive and informative question title.Telling us your code doesn't work and you're confused is neither.

Comment: Step 2: Learn to use the debugger to step through the code to see what's happening. It's extremely useful (and educational).

Answer (score 4):

All your number ranges need to be like this `Case 0 to  50`

With the way you have Excel is trying to do the math.

So on the first Case is looking for `w` to equal `-50` because `0-50=-50`.

The second is looking for `w` to equal `-8` because `51-59=-8`.

Comment: I get the downvote on an answer on a possible CV question, but the question is valid (horrible title tho).  Anybody with CV privs should be able to edit the Q title.  The error of how to write a select case is a valid point for future users.

Comment: @Chrismas007 what is CV?  So many times I have been told to move my comments to answers. Should I have left this as a comment?

Comment: CV is Close Vote.  I was speaking to the person who downvoted your answer.